# Annualized Return in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am seeking to confirm that my representation of the annualized return formula (using monthly returns) is optimal.

The annualized return formula I am using (where M is a monthly return and D is the total count of monthly returns) where the count of monthly returns is greater than 12 is as follows:

[image: formula]

Alternatively, the this would change in the case of the monthly return count being less than 12:

[image: formula]

Here is my representation of this formula in Pandas:

```
ann_return = observations.apply(lambda y: y.apply(lambda x: x+1))
ann_return = (ann_return.prod() ** (np.min(12/len(ann_return.index.values)) if len(ann_return.index.values) > 12 else 12/len(ann_return.index.values)))-1
```

Comment: What columns do you have in the dataframe? Can you give an example of a dataframe?

Comment: I don't know what that caret symbol between 1 and 12 is supposed to mean.

Comment: @piRSquared: The caret / wedge symbol between 1 and 12/D is displayed to denote the minimum value [link](http://www.numericana.com/answer/symbol.htm#chevron)

Comment: @DYZ: There is only one column in the dataframe, which is a list of monthly returns. The index is a series of corresponding monthly dates.

Comment: @northernthinking Is `D` the same for all rows, then?

Comment: @DYZ: `D` is the rowcount as each row contains a monthly return

Comment: @northernthinking Let me ask you again: Is `D` the same for all rows? Is it a constant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Formula

```
D = len(ann_return)
ann_return.add(1).prod() ** (12 / D) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the missing subtraction by one at the end of formula. Wouldn't the python code need to display this as well?

Comment: The first formula is what I think is correct.  The second formula is respecting what you've come up with and presenting you with a way of calculating it.  The `- 1` is embedded in the boolean value `D < 12`.  When `D < 12`, that `True` value will evaluate to `1`.  When `False` it evaluates to `0`. This captures the if statement for you.

Comment: Understood, I believe the subtraction by one is unconditional. What was supposed to be conditional is the exponent calculation.

`exponent = 12/D if D > 12 else: exponent = min(1,12/D)`

This was inspired by the following direction: [Mr Excel link](http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=1116377), which I am having a difficult time seeing the value of.

Based on your response and further review, I believe the most efficient and correct line would be:

`(df.add(1).prod() ** (12/len(df.index.values)))-1`

Comment: OH! You mean to subtract one from the entire thing?  Ahhh, that makes so much more sense.  This subtraction of 1 is in the exponent.  Forget that.  I hope I understand what your thinking now.  Otherwise my exuberance may have just confused things further.

Answer (score 3):

This calculates the annualized return percentage. It works with both an individual number or a Pandas dataframe. In the latter case, the first argument `percent` and optionally the second argument `months` can be a dataframe.

This was tested with Python 3.7.0 and Pandas 0.23.4 with NumPy 1.15.2.

```
def annualize_return(percent: float, months: int) -> float:
    """Return the annualized return percentage given the holding return percentage and the number of months held.

    >>> annualize_return(1.5, 1)  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    19.56...
    >>> annualize_return(6.1, 3)  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    26.72...
    >>> annualize_return(30, 12)  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    30.00...
    >>> annualize_return(30, 15)  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    23.35...
    >>> annualize_return(float('nan'), 15)
    nan
    >>> annualize_return(0, 0)
    0

    References:
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holding_period_return
        https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Annualized-Portfolio-Return
    """
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52618808/
    if months == 0:
        return percent
    rate = percent / 100
    years = months / 12
    rate = ((rate + 1)**(1 / years)) - 1
    percent = rate * 100
    return percent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True, exclude_empty=True)
```