# How to select n number of rows then move by 1

Tags: python, finance

I would like to calculate the rolling annualised return from my dataframe using quarterly returns and then move down to the following row, etc.
i.e:

```
Date          Q Return  1 year Return
30/09/2014      2%           -
31/12/2014      4%          -
31/03/2015      -6%         -
30/06/2015      8%         7.69%
30/09/2015      3%          8.75%
31/12/2015      -2%          2.47%
```

...
Obviously it is very simple with Excel, however I am struggling a little on python to have the moving annualised return.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annualized Return in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293677/annualized-return-in-pandas) (Pandas is an incredibly powerful and often-used data analysis library for Python.)

Answer (score 0):

`df.rolling(n).mean()` seems to be one of the solutions.

`n` should be 4 in this case.

But, you should transform the strings(I mean the `2%`, it seems to be the string) into floats. And finally replace the NaN with the `-` as you wish in the format of the pic.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful. just for future reference if someone is looking at annualizing performance:

```py
df['Annualised1Y'] = df['Q_Return'].rolling(4).apply(lambda x: ((np.prod(1+x)-1)*100))
```

or for a longer period:

```py
df['Annualised3Y'] = df['Q_Return'].rolling(12).apply(lambda x: ((np.prod(1+x)**(1/3)-1)*100))
```

hope this will help an investment analyst in the need to automate annualize return in the future.